# Warning: shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array

Tags: php, shuffle

why like this?

```
Warning: shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, resource given in /home/u801961841/public_html/img.php on line 12
```

Real PHP Code :

```
    <?php
require_once 'masterfile.php';
    $text3 = wordwrap($t[0], 31, "\n", true);
    $box = @ImageTTFBBox(23,0,'/home/u801961841/public_html/nama.TTF',$user[name]);
    $textwidth = abs($box[4] - $box[0]);
    $x_finalpos = 255-($textwidth/2);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img_empty.jpg');
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img_empty1.jpg');
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img_empty2.jpg');
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img_empty3.jpg');
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img_empty4.jpg');
shuffle($image);
    $font_color = ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
```

please help me to solve this problem: (

Comment: The error message seems to be very clear :X

Answer (score 6):

You're not setting `$image` as an array. Do this:

```
$image[] = imagecreatefromjpeg('img_empty.jpg');
$image[] = imagecreatefromjpeg('img_empty1.jpg');
$image[] = imagecreatefromjpeg('img_empty2.jpg');
$image[] = imagecreatefromjpeg('img_empty3.jpg');
$image[] = imagecreatefromjpeg('img_empty4.jpg');
```

Comment: but he became so well:
Warning: imagecolorallocate(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /home/u801961841/public_html/img.php on line 13

Warning: imagettftext() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in /home/u801961841/public_html/img.php on line 14

Warning: imagettftext() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in /home/u801961841/public_html/img.php on line 15

Answer (score 2):

`$image` isn't an array, it's an image resource.

Throw each `$image` into an array and then shuffle

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you right you need take random picture?

```
$images = array(
'img_empty.jpg',
'img_empty1.jpg',
'img_empty2.jpg',
'img_empty3.jpg',
'img_empty4.jpg'     
);

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($images[array_rand($images)]);
$font_color = ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
```

In this way you only allocate resources to picture required.

Comment: Thanks ;) hope you are rich and successful!

Comment: @Aurimas Don't forget that this comes off as accepted answer whoring.